# Binding to complex object on Xamarin Forms page not triggered by data refresh

Tags: xamarin.forms, model-binding

In my Xamarin Forms application I have a class which has a number of properties and methods on it that I am then using as a backing field for a `BindableProperty`. When I receive data from a web service I am then calling a method on my object which causes the underlying properties in that object to change.
In my XAML view I have bindings to all those properties but nothing is getting output to the screen and the data isn’t changing. `HandlePageViewModelChanged` gets called only once, when the page is created and not after data is received and the method on my object is called.

Perhaps a few code snippets will help:

```
public BindableProperty PageViewModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PageViewModel), typeof(MyCustomObjectModel), typeof(MyCustomObject), 
            propertyChanged: HandlePageViewModelChanged);

        private static void HandlePageViewModelChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            //Something in here?
        }

        public MyCustomObjectModel PageViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyCustomObjectModel)GetValue(PageViewModelProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(PageViewModelProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

Later in the page lifecycle when I receive data from a web service I then call:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventData>(output);
PageViewModel.RegisterData(data);
```

My View, to test, has been simplified to:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20" BindingContext="PageViewModel">
        <Label Text="{Binding Field1}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding PageViewModel.Field1}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Where Field1 is a public property on the PageViewModel object (which is an instance of my class).

Any ideas why this data binding isn’t working and how I might fix it?
Thanks

Comment: You probably want to look into the INotifyPropertyChanged interface

Comment: what does your viewmodel/code behind look like ?